# How to start application automatically when bluetooth device is connected?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, automation

Whenever I enter my car, bluetooth is connected. What I would like is my speedcam alert application to be started once BT is connected and ideally terminate application when disconnected. I am using LG G6 with Nougat.

Answer (score 6):

For such automation purposes, you can use any one of the following-

1. [IFTTT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt&hl=en) (if this happens then do this)
2. [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)
3. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) (paid app)

Takser is somewhat difficult to use and paid app so I will recommend you to use IFTTT or Automate. 
IFTTT has supports for a variety of products such as Phillips Hue lights etc. But Automate is the easiest to use for your purpose.

Comment: Great! do you have any experience on which one is using less resources? Are they going to run as background service, eating CPU time or the system will run automation app whenever certain event is fired?

Comment: I have used automate which is not very resource hungry and I am not sure about working of it but I think it checks at regular intervals.

Comment: Turns out terminate part is impossible unless my phone is rooted, which is not possible at the moment...

Comment: Well every automation has its limit without all the privileges :)

Answer (score 5):

For LG phones specifically you can use Smart Settings to automatically open apps when a specific Bluetooth device is connected, among other things.

To get to the Smart Settings, go to the Settings app, navigate to the General tab, then tap on Smart Settings.

Comment: wow, I missed that function. It does half of the job indeed, will try it. Sadly there is no option to kill the app. Maybe I use automation for killing it when BT disconnected...

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer by Deepak Gangwar, might I also suggest [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)? Among other things I use it to change the in-call volume whenever I connect my BT headset. With BT it detects the specific device paired, so it can do different things for e.g. BT headset or car. It comes as both free and paid app. The free versions has a limit to how many macros you can define (I'm not sure about the exact limit, but it is quite low), but is otherwise fully functional.

I'm not in any way affiliated with ArloSoft. Just a happy MacroDroid user.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give it a try as well. Having more choice is always good.